# Can you create an Express Router handler for all the verbs that don't already have handlers for a given endpoint?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an API endpoint that will only be used with POSTs.  If I make a request to that endpoint with any other HTTP verb I get a rather ugly, non-JSON response: `Cannot POST /path/to/api`.  It would be nice if I could make one statement that handles the rest of the HTTP verbs that haven't been explicitly defined (eg: `router.other('/path/to/api', function () { ... });`

I tried using `router.all('/path/to/api', function () { ... });` and it seemed to do what I want, however based on what is given in the [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router.all), it doesn't seem to be the proper solution to the problem.  Would `router.all()` be an acceptable solution if I know that that I call `res.*` in the POST function?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.all()` actually [adds separate route handlers](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/661435256384165bb656cb7b6046b4138ca24c9e/lib/application.js#L444-L454) for every (supported) HTTP method, which can be inefficient since Express will potentially have to check each method individually.

If you want more of a single catchall solution, you might use `.use()` instead, which will catch everything while only adding one route handler:

```
router.post(....)
      .use(function(req, res, next) {
        // ...
      });
```

Comment: Ok, that seems reasonable.  So as long as I call something like `res.json(...)` in `.post(...)` I shouldn't hit `.use(...)`?

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like a reasonable use-case for `.all` to me. I'd recommend using chaining on your route to simplify the grouping as well, e.g.

```
router.other('/path/to/api')
    .post(function(req, res){
        // Handle the API request.
    })
    .all(function(req, res){
        // Respond with an error about invalid METHODs.
    });
```